# How to execute bind variables in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, bind-variables

I was learning about bind variables in pl/sql and tried to execute the following code on oracle 10g database

```
VARIABLE v_bind1 VARCHAR2(10);
EXEC :v_bind1:='shweta';
```

when i executed it, one pop-up asking for bind variable came as shown in the picture
[screenshot of pop up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLjo.png)

Then I entered the value 'shweta' in it and submitted, but it shows *invalid sql statement.*

what should I enter in the pop-up box, so that my program execute successfully?

Comment: This behaviour seems to be coming from some web-based app development tool, not PL/SQL the programming language. It looks like the tool doesn't emulate SQL\*Plus `variable`, `exec` or bind variable syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you use Apex SQL Workshop, its *ancient* version (2.1) which dates in January 2006, was part of 10g Express Edition database. I never thought that someone might still be using it. Upgrade to at least 11gXE, it is free.

I suggest you test your skills in **SQL*Plus** instead because responses you get from tool you chose might be misleading.